# Test Spring for case when context should not even load

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

I would like to test my Spring Boot application against case when no config file is given. In such situation application should throw exception when creating bean `MyConfig`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyConfig myConfig() throws IOException {
        if (no config file) throw new NoConfigFileException();
    }
}
```

I have a test which tests if Spring application's context is built:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:file_with_existing_config_file_path.properties")
public class MyApplicationTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

This test fails - as expected (since `myConfig` method throws `NoConfigFileException`). Unfortunately I cannot "turn the light to green" using annotation `@Test(expected = NoConfigFileException.class)`.

Where should I expect exception if not in the only one test method I got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golden rule when you are writing automated tests is -> cover one test case per test method (unless you are having parametrized test). It seems to me that you are thinking about breaking that rule.

Consider separate test class (where you don't specify properties file) which is testing only this aspect or your logic. That way you can use `@Test(expected = NoConfigFileException.class)`.

BTW, I would suggest to look into Spring Boot feature [@ConfigurationProperties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties). You can use Java EE validation (e.g. @NotNull) for your properties.

That way you can enforce application to find the file and fail it early if no config file is loaded into Spring Context.

Comment: Thanks, I must have forgot this rule :) it's much easier now.